# Open() for output not creating file

Tags: c, file-io

I have this function that utilizes open to set i/o redirection:

```
void setOutput(char * buffer){
    int file = open(buffer, O_WRONLY || O_CREAT, S_IWUSR);
    if(file < 0){ printf("error opening %s for output\n", buffer); }
    if(dup2(file, 1) < 0){ printf("error with dup2 opening %s for output\n", buffer); }

}
```

When I run it, it works fine for files that are already defined but returns -1 when it receives a non-created file. Not sure why

Comment: I think it should be  O_WRONLY | O_CREAT

Comment: `O_WRONLY || O_CREAT` is a boolean expression that yields `1` that is `O_WRONLY`. Fix it by replacing with `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT`.

Comment: @GreenScape, you have also commented it with a mistake, please correct it. It can be confusing for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the following

```
int file = open(buffer, O_WRONLY || O_CREAT, S_IWUSR);
```

To

```
int file = open(buffer, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IWUSR);
```

Format :

`int  open(  char  *filename,  int  access,  int  permission  );`

access : Should be provided as a bit wise OR operator, that means using **|** not **||** which is logical OR

Comment: I'm also getting permission denied for files that I create. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Go through this :  http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:open . You can set permissions for your requirement to.. May be also you might not permit to create files with your privilege status..

Comment: Also for my understanding you open the file to read ? So please change the access and permission requirement accordingly :)

Comment: Ah I mean when I go to it in vim it says permission denied as well. Not sure what's wrong. Additionally when the files are created and I try to do it again, both files give bad file descriptor